# Can I create just one mailform.php to deal with an email form page

Tags: php

Tutorials all over the web say that you need two pages for a mailform PHP for someone to send a simple email message, with email, subject and message from your website.

Can you get away with just one PHP mail form page, which creates another page , which says *"thank you for your interest in our site"* ?

Comment: Yes, you can both have the form output and the mail processing in one script. A simple `if` will do.

Comment: I figured out how to use 2 pages, which i should use, for formating the contact page.

Answer (score -2):

if i understand you right, you need to implement accounts in your site and if the account is and administrator - to show the reply form, otherwise to show a feedback form